# Percents with Python

Tags: python

I would like to get one program working. I almost have it, but some things still cause errors.

Main idea is that program would do these things:

- Ask from user % of free throws that hits ( 1 - 100 int)
- Stimulates with while 1000 throws and with every throw it calculates if it hits or misses.
- There must be one line about every throw: hits or misses.'
- Sums up all throws that hits and finally prints it.

Example:

```
Insert %  of free throws: 45
1. throw hits
2. throw hits
3. throw misses
4. throw hits
...
997. throw misses
998. throw misses
999. throw hits
1000. throw misses
Hits 458 throws.
```

I have created this:

```
from random import randint
percent = int(input("Insert % of free throws: "))
var = 1
hits = 0
while var < 1000:
if randint(1, 100) <= percent:
    var = var + 1
    print(str(var) + '. throw hits')
    hits = hits + var 
else:
    print(str(var) + '. throw misses')

print("Hits " + str(hits) + " throws.")
```

But there are some errors. First of all, if I insert 0% then it goes crazy and the second one is , that the hit count is ridiculous - like 500500 and so on. I have idea that **var != 0** but it's still not working and count thing is still mystery for me. I have tried to but 'hits' before and after var but it still won't work.
Anyone have ideas to get me on right track?

Comment: You need to indent the body of `while`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're only incrementing `var` when you get a hit, you should be incrementing it for every throw. So just use a simple `for` loop.

And you should increment `hits` by just 1 every time there's a hit, not by `var`.

```
for var in range(1, 1001):
    if randint(1, 100) <= percent:
        hits += 1
        print(str(var) + '. throw hits')
    else:
        print(str(var) + '. throw misses')
print ("Hits " + str(hits) " throws.")
```

Note that `range()` does not include the end number in the range, so to get 1,000 throws starting with `var = 1`, you have to use `1001` as the end.

Answer (score 1):

Barmar picked up on the reason for the weirdness in your result values, so let me just pick out some points for review since this is an illustrative code sample.

The "standard" way of doing weighted distributions in Python is:

```
random.random() < pct
```

Where pct is a fraction of 1, e.g 45% -> 0.45. This changes your code to:

```
percent = int(input("Insert % of free throws: ")) / 100

...
    if random.random() < percent:
        ...
```

Other nitpicks include avoiding `while` loops whenever possible. It's rare that you need a `while` loop in Python that isn't `while True`. Use a `for` loop, especially since you're trying to track the loop index! Combine that with a few other tweaks and you get...

```
hitcount = 0

for i in range(1, 1001):  # loop from 1 -> 1000 inclusive
    if random.random() < percent:
        hitcount += 1
        msg = "{}. throw hits".format(i)
    else:
        msg = "{}. throw misses".format(i)
    print(msg)
print("Hit {} throws.".format(hitcount))
```

Notably this uses `str.format` instead of string building with the `%` operator. This is preferred.